# Allowing users to click on links on an auto refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, page-refresh

I have a website [here](http://billischill.ga) and I would like users to be able to click links and or buttons inside of the chat windows but the page is auto refreshing at a very high rate using jQuery, what would be the most efficient way to allow this?

Here is my code for auto refreshing.

```
//Load the file containing the chat log
function loadLog(){     
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "chatLogs/masterlog.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
            }               
        },
    });
}
setInterval (loadLog, 500); //Reload file every 2.5 seconds
```

Comment: Perhaps disable the auto-scrolling if the mouse is over the chat box?

Comment: I would not update the full contents, but only update on change + add new content. Usually for a chat, you would only add more lines, but never change any old entries. So why bother updating them continuously in the first place?

You could also use some virtual DOM framework like react.js to do this for you. Or you could use the data handling parts of d3.js for this.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to implement a feature like when the user hold CTRL key pressed (or any other key) it stop the refreshing.
when the user release the key, it start again.
you could implement this simply like this :

```
//Load the file containing the chat log
function loadLog(){     
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "chatLogs/masterlog.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
            }               
        },
    });
}
var i = setInterval (loadLog, 500); //Reload file every 2.5 seconds

document.onkeydown = function(e){
    ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
    if(ctrl)
        clearInterval(i);
}


document.onkeydown = function(e){
    ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
    if(ctrl)
        i = setInterval(loadLog, 500);
}
```

Comment: this looks like a good idea but I am just wondering if I could do it right off the bat so I could display iframes etc. without then refreshing automatically and messing up